# How to get reference of the parent list box item in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

```
<Window> <!-- DataContext="HomeViewModel" -->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Discs}"> <!-- HomeViewModel.ObservableCollection<DiscViewModel> -->
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}"> <!-- DiscViewModel.IList<Folder> -->
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <cc:TreeViewItemEx Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.GetFilesCommand}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

I want to execute `GetFilesCommand` (defined by `DiscViewModel`) when `Folder` is expanded. For this I extended `TreeViewItem` with `Command` as `DependencyProperty`, and executed this command in `OnExpanded` (overriden). This works but `Command` is set to null. The reason is stated in error below:

> 'GetFilesCommand' property not found on 'object' ''HomeViewModel'
>   (HashCode=22799085)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.GetFilesCommand; DataItem='ListBox'
>   (Name=''); target element is 'TreeViewItemEx' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

I understand the error, but not how to fix that XAML so that it picks command from `DiscViewModel` bound to current list item?

Answer (score 0):

Ah my bad! I need almonds, it seems.

Changed

```
AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}
```

To

```
AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}
```

With former code, it picked up `ListBox`'s `DataContext` and therefore complained about command not found in `HomeViewModel` which is `DataContext` for `ListBox`.

Chose not to delete the question, because I am sure someone might stumble upon similar issue in future.